# Chrome extension - Share data between view and the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension to debrid and stream a link on my raspberry pi (running Kodi).

So far, it's working well. I can give a link :

[image]

and it's debrided + streamed on Kodi.

I would like to make it easier to use.

Instead of pasting the link into the app, I made a little script to search on a given type of page if a link can be debrided via Realdebrid and is so, the script add a button to directly stream it :

[image]

The problem here is :
When the user click on the button, how can I pass the link to my extension ? I would like to have it in my extension because I can display the link into history.

I tried something like that :

- from the view : 
  [image]
- from the extension :
  [image]

But it's not working.

I think I should use [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) but I don't understand how.

It's an **open source** project that you can find on [Github](https://github.com/maxime1992/real-debrid-stream).
As it's not working yet you won't find the code I shared in the 2 images before. It's just on my computer, not pushed.

Any help would be really appreciated !

Thanks !

**EDIT 1 :**

When I click on the button injected in the page, I get this error :
[image]

Which leads to this line : 
[image]

**EDIT 2 :**
[image]

If I keep the app open while I click on the button it's working. But I do not want to have to launch the app of course, the goal is to click on the button only.

Comment: I don't think "request:any" is the correct syntax in ES6. You must be getting a syntax error near this line by your transpiler.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I do not have error on compilation. Please see my *edit 1* for more infos about the error.

Comment: Seems like you aren't getting the response from the popup (extension), which means that your if-condition for `sendResponse` is most probably `false`. Try putting `console.log(request)` before the `if-block` to see what request you are getting.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Aaaah you're right ! If I keep the app open and I click on the button, I get the anwser :). CF *edit 2*. Now, how can I do to DO NOT have to launch the app first ?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Post code, and errors, as text instead.

Comment: @Xan sorry about that, won't do it again you're right.

Answer (score 2):

`Popup script` is loaded when you open the app by a user action i.e clicking on the app icon. Until then, it is not available to you. As such you are getting this error because when you send a request the listener should be available and in your case its not there.

Now, the easiest way to  achieve this would be to send the request from the content script to the background page which is available even when the app is not open.

1. Inject the button using the content script and send a message to the background page (called event pages) on click event of the button.
2. Add an event listener in your background page which will listen to the request from the content script and store the link in the local storage.
3. When your app opens just load the link from the local storage and display your links in the history.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  
Is this the simplest way ? I'll try it out this we or next week because I'm really busy right now (school). I'll come back here to let you know :) Thanks again !

Comment: Actually there's a problem. It's cool that I can store the link with local storage ... But still. How do I send the link to Kodi ? I'll have to open the app and launch it from history ? I could just open and paste it.

Comment: The things you are doing when the `popup (app)` is open can be done when its not open by using the background page. I see in your code, when the url is pasted in the app, you are first getting the link from the `real debrid` and then sending the link to `kodi`. Repeat the same process when you get this link from the content script. The main thing is to get the link without opening the app and that is what you will get from the content script.